# Shell command no longer working

Tags: terminal, script

I'm on a M1 MacBook Pro running macOS 12.3.1. I've had some AppleScripts that perform a shell script run happily for many years. For some unknown reason these have just stopped working today - nothing has changed that I'm aware of.

Here's the shell script that I'm trying to run:

```
cd 'Users/jsmith/Backup Testing'; /usr/bin/zip -r '/Volumes/Backups/ Projects/12052022 181915.zip' 'Databases'
```

which is returning the following error when I run this manually in the Terminal app:

```
cd: no such file or directory: Users/jsmith/Backup Testing
zip warning: name not matched: Databases
```

I can't see what has changed here to cause this as it was working fine a few days ago and isn't today and I haven't installed any new software that I can recall in the past few days.

The paths to the folders are correct and I've checked them many times so the Databases folder and the parent folder definitely do exist here.

Comment: You need a slash before Users.

Comment: Does it work when you open a terminal and do the commands manually ? Did you make any modification in your home director ? Yes your script started by root or another user ?

Comment: You talk about an Applescript running a shell script, but then just show two shell commands. Can you provide some context here, e.g. showing the relevant part of the AppleScript which calls out to the shell here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a leading slash before `Users` resolved this for me. Strangely this has worked for many years without issue so still puzzled as to why this stopped working. The AppleScript was simply just calling `do shell script myScriptName`

Comment: The working directory a script is run with is generally unpredictable, so using relative paths (those that don't start with "/") is generally a bad idea. Apparently, the method you use used to run it with `/` (the filesystem root) as the working directory, but that's changed. I have no idea why it used to be `/` or why it changed, but I can tell you that problems like this are the reason relative paths are a bad idea.